# python how to iteratively export plots and text to html

Tags: python, html, image, matplotlib

I have a loop to create matplotlib figures:

```
x1 = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
x2 = np.array([1,3,3,8,5])
x3 = np.array([9,2,5,4,5])
n = 30
for i in n:
     print(f"============{i}==========")
     fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 3,  figsize=[18, 10])
     axs[0].plot(x1)
     axs[1].plot(x2)
     ax2[2].plot(x3)
```

It all presented nicely in my nb but how want to export it to an HTML with all the text and the images.
What is the based way to do so?

Comment: Can you give a more concrete **reproducible** example with a small sample dataset?

Comment: @mozway added mock data

Comment: if you want html interactive plot, `plotly` is your best option

Comment: I dont want interactive plot. Just a static regular HTML. Simply export the generated plots to a static HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a function to convert the figures to base64:

```
def fig2html(fig):
    import base64, io
    b = io.BytesIO()
    fig.savefig(b, format='png')
    b64 = base64.b64encode(b.getvalue()).decode('utf-8')
    return f'<img src=\'data:image/png;base64,{b64}\'>'
```

Example with your data:

```
x1 = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
x2 = np.array([1,3,3,8,5])
x3 = np.array([9,2,5,4,5])
n = 2

html_data = []
for i in range(n):
    html_data.append(f'<p>{i}</p>')
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 3,  figsize=[3, 2])
    axs[0].plot(x1)
    axs[1].plot(x2)
    axs[2].plot(x3)
    html_data.append(fig2html(fig))

simple_template = '<html>\n%s\n</html>'
html = simple_template % '\n'.join(html_data)
```

output:

```
<html>
<p>0</p>
<img src='data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGg...'>
<p>1</p>
<img src='data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGg...'>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks, it plotting the figures but what about adding the text between iterations?

Comment: @okuoub What is wrong with `html_data.append(f'<p>=== {i} ===</p>')`?